# Puzzle: Betting on basketball games strategy

Tags: puzzle, gambling

This is a question I saw as an interview question, that I cannot figure out.

Devise a method for betting on the *individual* games of a basketball series so that if your team wins the series, you win \$100, and if they lose the series, you lose \$100.

Series' are 7 games, and the first team to win 4 games wins the series (so a team could win after 4,5,6, or 7 games). The problem is, how do we devise a strategy for individual games, so that no matter the sequence of games, you get a predictable amount at the end? I cannot think of anything...

Comment: Work from the end. Suppose the teams have played 6 games already; how much profit/loss do you need to have accumulated over the first 6 bets, and how much must you bet on game 7? Now suppose the teams have played 5 games already; first suppose your team is ahead 3-2; how much profit/loss do you need to have accumulated so that your bet on game 6 gets you $100 total if your team wins, or puts you into the after-6-games situtation above if you lose? And so on.